# Unable to install postgresql-server through preseed

Tags: server, apt, system-installation, postgresql, preseed

I am trying make unattended ubuntu-server-16.04.3 iso image. I have updated isolinux.cfg and txt.cfg to take the new preseed file. All I need is unattended ubuntu server with postgres server running.

Here is my seed file:
https://pastebin.com/xDpViuaw

I didn't add any new deb's. Same ISO image if tried manually, I can select postgresql server from option and I can easily complete it.

I have tried so many links and it always ended with below error as in attached image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLvLl.png

If i remove postgresql from preseed file, i can complete the installation without any errors.

Can anyone point me how to resolve it?
Anything I am missing/doing wrong in preseed file?

PS: partitions are done as part of kickstart file

Answer (score 0):

This might not be helpful, but it is worth a try. Did you try to use the netboot image as base image?

If you want to try the netboot image, you could fork our [lightweight project](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/).

Comment: Interesting but sadly this doesn't help me.

Comment: Did you try? I tested it, and it works perfectly well.

[Here](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/tree/example/postgresql-on-16.04/ubuntu/16.04) you will find the complete working example (at branch "example/postgresql-on-16.04").